# How current run in conductor by electrons

Tags: current

When we connect neutral to ground, why doesn't an electron deficiency occur in the conducting power lines. I know current in a conductor is made up of flowing electrons but when this current is flowing into ground, then the electrons in that conductor must be flowing into the ground as well.  Why doesn't this result in a depletion of electrons in the electrical grid?

Comment: "current goes to ground": no, it doesn't. Somewhere else, the same current needs to flow from ground into the grid. Current always flows in a cycle.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  It does flow to ground at load, but *because* it flowed from ground at the source.   Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Thanks for answer but as far I know ground is 0v. So ground can only take electrons but we can not take back electrons from ground.  Can you explain me bit more please

Comment: Think of water in a lake/ocean.  Is it impossible to move that water uphill?  No, it just takes energy.

Answer (score 1):

> ... but when current going to ground than all electrons going to ground as well.

No. If current is flowing out one end of a cable then current must be flowing in the other.

> Then why there is no shortage of electrons in grid.

Because current flows in circuits which are closed loops. No circuit - no current.

Simple experiment: connect one end of a battery to ground with a multimeter on mA DC range.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBEArE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An open circuit. How much current do you think will flow?*

Note: do not connect your multimeter in amps mode across the battery terminals. A high current will result and it may damage your meter.

---

From comments below the question:

> Thanks for answer but as far I know ground is 0v. So ground can only take electrons but we can not take back electrons from ground.

Ground can accept or supply electric charge. If it couldn't then alternating current couldn't flow through it.

Answer (score 0):

See the diagram below.  When connecting the neutral wire to ground, there is no circuit completed across the voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3dt2a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Because if the current goes to ground which are electrons then at the time the same amount of current will enter in the circuit Kirchoff current law total incoming current is equal to total outgoing current so if the current is going to ground then there must be a point in the circuit which is attached to ground then it will suck current from that point so no shortage of electron

Answer (score 0):

You have in incorrect picture of what electric current really is and what is going on.

Imagine a circular tube filled with ping-pong balls.  Something very much like this cat toy, but with balls filling the entire circumference instead of just one ball.

[image]
The balls are very tightly packaged with only a single small gap in the entire ball chain.

This circular tube is a conductor.  If you reach your finger (or paw) in and push one of the balls, you end up moving all the balls because one ball pushes the next.  Indeed, you can bat at the balls over and over and keep all of them spinning around the entire ring, faster and faster.

Does the circular tube ever develop a ball deficiency?  Are the balls consumed or otherwise leaving the tube? Of course not!  Yet there is still motion, or flow, of the balls.

Electrical current works the same way.  The electrons are the balls, while you can also think of positive holes as gaps where there isn't an electron/ball.  They're like bubbles in water.

For a clearer image of this, we can think of a conductive cable as a straight tube of ping-pong balls, open on either end.  Only, the ping pong balls are in this tube fairly tight, tight enough that they won't fall out or otherwise move due to external motion or gravity.

To make a ball pop out of one of the ends of the tube, you have to add a ping pong ball on the other end.  If you push in a new ball, it will make the ball at the other end pop out.

This process makes the balls flow, and you can repeat it for as long as you want, and you will never run out of balls because for every ball that pops out of the tube, you also had to add a ball to the tube on the other end.

And this is how electrical current works as well.  For electrons to flow through a conductor, you always have the same number of electrons going into the conductor as you do going out of it.

If you disconnect one end of the conductor, you can force in (or pull out) a certain number of electrons per volt.  This number scales linearly with the voltage - if you double the voltage, you can push or pull twice as many electrons into our out of the conductor.  But no more than that.

What I just described is, in fact, capacitance.  A farad (the unit of capacitance) is a coulomb per volt.  It is a measure of how much charge (or put another way, how many electrons) you can push or pull in or out of something per each volt of electric field you apply to it.

As you remove electrons, this creates a charge imbalance in the form of positive holes, or gaps where electrons would normally be.  Since the electrons are attracted to these holes, eventually you reach an equilibrium where a given voltage is perfectly counteracted by the attractive force of the holes, and no more electrons can be removed.  But this is very much the opposite of conduction.  Any capacitor requires some sort of gap that prevents electrons from flowing.  For a conductor to ever actually **lose** electrons, it must be galvanically isolated on one end.  In any circuit however, a conductor will have electrons flowing through it without ever actually losing or gaining any.

> when current going to ground than all electrons going to ground as well

Actually, electrons come ***from*** ground typically.  For example, in a DC circuit, the ground or negative terminal of a battery is the **source** of electrons.  Remember, electrons are negative.

But even for the literal ground - the soil, dirt, the Earth itself, things are no different from what I just described.  The ground (like the actual soil or dirt) is very much conductive, and while it isn't nearly as conductive as most metals, it doesn't really matter because there is **just so much of it.**  Even a resistive material can be very low resistance if you have a big enough cross section of said material.

The Earth provides a convenient common voltage reference, and when a grid level system is grounded, we are simply bonding neutral to the same voltage potential of the earth.  And while normally no current flows through the actual soil of the Earth (rather, it returns via the neutral wire), there is nothing actually preventing current flowing through the literal ground.

In fact, when current *does* flow through the ground (as in, the dirt), it is referred to as **fault current.**  Because this really only happens when there is some sort of grid-level electrical fault happening somewhere.  In this case, the Earth itself will readily act like a neutral wire and current will flow (typically in a region underneath the power lines involved in this fault current, though much more spread out in the ground), and ultimately flow into the transformer secondary that is supplying that set of power lines.

So all current that flows into the Earth or neutral locally is ultimately flowing back into the transformer winding at the other end, which then flows into the power lines, which then flows into the load and returns through neutral, or during faults, the ground of the Earth, many many miles back into the transformer and so on and so fourth.  There are no electrons getting 'used up' or leaving this loop, for all current that flows out of a conductor, there is just as much current/charge carriers flowing into it.

That is why we refer to these things as ***circuits.***  Because they are circular.  Electricity only flows in loops, with no net gain or loss of total charge if you look at the complete conduction path.

Everything I've described has been from the standpoint of DC current, but none of this actually changes for AC current.  AC current is still flowing like DC current, the only difference is it reverses direction and flows the other direction as much as it did the first direction.  But at least over the span of a half cycle, it is no different than DC current.  Regardless, you still need loops.

The one exception is the capacitance example.  When you pull some electrons off of some disconnected conductor (like one plate of a capacitor) then an electric field is generated from the charge imbalance which causes an equal number of extra electrons to be pushed onto nearby conductors, attracted by the positive electric field.  Or, put another way, for every electron you remove from one plate of a capacitor, another electron is forced onto the opposite plate.  This creates a charge imbalance on each plate individually, but the number of electrons inside the capacitor, on both plates, does not change.  They just increasingly are removed from one plate and forced onto the other.

But with AC, you move some on, but then pull them back off when the current reverses direction.  This allows AC actually conduct through a capacitor almost as if it were physically connected, albeit with some impedance and phase shift.  Imagine our tube of ping pong balls again, but there is a rubber membrane in one spot, partitioning the balls into two sections and they cannot actually flow.  But you can push one section of balls a bit, stretching the membrane and pushing the balls across it a little bit, then you can do the same but from the reverse direction.  The balls don't really move except by however much the membrane lets them, perhaps one width of one ping pong ball.  But you can wiggle them back and forth to your heart's content (or cat's delight) and electrical current is just these balls, or electrons flowing.  Wiggling is as good as flow for getting work done.

But that isn't really even relevant in this context of the power grid - I just wanted to note that one difference with AC.  Otherwise, everything still holds the same as it does for DC.  Indeed, most new high voltage transmission lines built are [HVDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current) lines, not AC.